# OpenLabs connector Magento OpenERP 7.0

Tags: python, magento, odoo, magento-1.9, openerp-7

I'm trying to connect my OpenERP 7.0 to my Magento webSite 1.9.

I'm using the connector developed by openLabs https://github.com/openlabs/magento_integration

I follow the instructions of https://openerp-magento-connector.readthedocs.io/en/develop/introduction.html#installation

But after 3 restores of my OpenERP, I still have an error when I tried to update my modules to get my Magento module.

> File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 617, in update_list
>       handler.load_addons()
>     File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 580, in load_addons
>       m = **import**('openerp.addons.' + module)
>     File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/modules/module.py", line 133, in load_module
>       mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)
>     File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/addons/magento_integration-develop/**init**.py", line 9, in 
>       import magento_
>     File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/addons/magento_integration-develop/magento_.py", line 17, in 
>       import magento
>   ImportError: No module named magento

I'm thinking this module isn't stable but when I read on forums, I saw people saying it works.

Some of this people or someone else can explain to me how they did ? Or another solution ? I'm open to multiple ways as it works. (But I haven't the possibility to upgrade my OpenERP in 8.0 or 9.0).

Thanks

EDIT : To @CZoellner

First, thx for your helpful answers

Ok, I solve the problem, my python lib was installed but my openERP installer didn't find it. So I modify the script to add the way of my module in sys.path. This error is resolved.

But now, I have another error seems the first

> File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/addons/magento_integration-develop/**init**.py", line 10, in 
>       import country
>     File "/opt/openerp/davidts/appserver-dts/parts/openerp-7.0-20140124-002431/openerp/addons/magento_integration-develop/country.py", line 18, in 
>       import pycountry
>   ImportError: No module named pycountry

and the sys.path has already the good way

> [...
>    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycountry-1.20-py2.7.egg',
>   ...]

I never develop in python so I certainly missed something

Comment: Did you install the magento python lib? on debian/ubuntu `pip install magento`

Comment: No, I didn't, but I restore again and I try with this and the error still appear.

Comment: if you've installed the magento python lib, the error message can't be the same!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So I again restoring my snapshot ...

But now, instead using the installer, I downloaded the library manually and install it one by one.

So I install, pycountry lib and magento lib. I update the file "magento_.py" and "pycountry.py" of openLab connector to add the path of my library on sys.path.

Something like that

> import sys
>   sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycountry-1.20-py2.7.egg/")

I run the setup of openLabs connector and after I launch update of openERP.

And it finally works ! whew !

Anyway thx for your useful answers !